# Google Sheets With OR in Query

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-query-language

I am using OR criteria in query to exclude data with specific text but it seems that OR criteria is not working. Check The below image in which I used the query function to exclude data where Column B is 'West' or 'East' but the its not working.

[image: Click To See The Image]

Any help on above will be appreciated.

Formula used:-

```
=QUERY(A1:B14,"Select * Where A is not null and (B<>'West' or B<>'East')")
```

Comment: Include code as text. It makes it easy to copy, test etc.

Comment: Thanks TheMaster, as suggested by you has copied the formula for ease of copy, test, etc.

Comment: Why do you say it's not working? A1 is not null, B1 is not "East". Both are true for C1

Comment: @ TheMaster thanks for your quick response, the result should exclude data where B  is 'West' or B is  'East' but still the result is showing data where B is West or East.

Comment: Then it should be `and`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A1 is not null, B1 is not "East". Both are true for C1. You're looking for `and`. See [De Morgan's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws): When you negate, you use `and`.

```
=QUERY(A1:B14,"Select * Where A is not null and B<>'West' and B<>'East'")
```

Or

```
=QUERY(A1:B14,"Select * Where A is not null and not (B='West' or B='East')")
```

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
=QUERY(A1:B14, "where A is not null and not B matches 'West|East'", )
```